# Script for wrapping an interactive service

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, systemd, services

On the server that I use we have a systemd service that is responsible for starting/stopping/restarting something but the interaction with the service is designed in an interactive way so for example if I try to restart the service `$ systemctl restart foo.service` it asks me for a username and password interactively. What I want to achieve is to have a script or some other way that wraps the service so I can call it like this: `script.sh <restart/start/stop> <username> <password>`. This would allow me to automate some things.

Comment: Is the username and password asked from the `foo` service, or from `systemctl`? If you were to run `systemctl` as root would you still get prompted for the username and password?

Comment: Yes it’s from the service itself @roaima

Comment: Does this service not provide you with an option to give these bits of data in some other form, like in a configuration file?

Answer (score 2):

`$ printf 'username\npassword\n' | systemctl restart foo.service`

Comment: Are you certain that the service would read from its standard input?